# Picture library migration from SP2007 to SP2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using custom master page, this custom master page was working perfect on MOSS2007 after migrate it showing these error, if i change master page to default master its work perfect.

My site picture library was working perfect in MOSS 2007 after migration there two issue in picture library..

1 - If click on any picture it give error 
Error Message
An unexpected error has occurred.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 543887d4-d68f-4a1f-81ce-e9bdc8cc569e

Date and Time: 12/12/2010 12:56:28

2- If we upload image it after browse when click ok button it process and shows error.
Error Message
An unexpected error has occurred.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 658613ed-467c-4a22-9d4e-8cc4238f25bf

Date and Time: 12/12/2010 12:58:34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the site in sharepoint desginer and validate if your master page contains all required content place holders